# Formatting Pivot Table (.NumberFormat)

Tags: excel, vba

**OBJECTIVE**

Pull in a normalized dataset. Place dataset into a pivot table.

**APPROACH**

1. Normalize Data
2. Select normalized data and create pivot table
3. Configure pivot table headings and columns
4. Format headings and columns

**CODE**

```
Sub createPivot()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As pivotCache
Dim pvt As pivotTable
Dim srcData As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startPvt As String
Dim target As Worksheet

'Delete previous pivottable
Worksheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange2.Clear

'Select pivot table data
Worksheets("CONSOLIDATED").Activate
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
srcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:H" & lastRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Set pivot table location
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PIVOT")
startPvt = target.Name & "!" & target.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create pivot cache
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=srcData)

'Deploy pivot table
Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=startPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")

    'Add Pivot Fields
    pvt.PivotFields("Fiscal Year").Orientation = xlColumnField
    pvt.PivotFields("Fiscal Year").Position = 1

    pvt.PivotFields("Fiscal Month").Orientation = xlColumnField
    pvt.PivotFields("Fiscal Month").Position = 2

    pvt.PivotFields("Unit").Orientation = xlRowField
    pvt.PivotFields("Unit").Position = 1

    pvt.PivotFields("Project").Orientation = xlRowField
    pvt.PivotFields("Project").Position = 2

    pvt.PivotFields("Base Expense").Orientation = xlDataField

    'Format cells
    pvt.PivotFields("Base Expense").NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"

End Sub
```

**ISSUE**

No errors, however `pvt.PivotFields("Base Expense").NumberFormat = "$ #,##0"` does not take effect.

Comment: I'm guessing the value field's name is actually something like "Sum of Base Expense".

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this macro a while ago to format my PivotTables. It should be pretty easy to modify the code to suit your needs. It loops through each of the value fields and changes the function to sum and formats the value.

```
Sub formatPivot()
    Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable
    Dim pvtName As String
    Dim pvtType As String
    Dim pvtFld As PivotField

    pvtName = ActiveCell.PivotTable.Name                ' Get the name of the active pivottable
    Set pvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtName)       ' set the pivot table to the active table

    ' Change to sum and update the number format
    For Each pvtFld In pvtTbl.DataFields
        pvtType = pvtFld                                    
        With pvtTbl.PivotFields(pvtType)
            .Function = xlSum
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For me this identified the name I should use which, as suggested by Doug Glancy above, includes the "Sum of..." part.

Answer (score -1):

I just discover today that you cannot NumberFormat a label field, only a data field, if that helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.numberformat

"Remarks
You can set the NumberFormat property only for a data field.

The format code is the same string as the Format Codes option in the Format Cells dialog box. The Format function uses different format code strings than do the NumberFormat and NumberFormatLocal properties."